# default open all accordion content and disable collapse over set screen size

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, menu, accordion

For my site design I need an accordion menu for screens smaller than a 7" horizontal tablet and a normal horizontal menu for everything over that with the content acting as a one page website (so all the accordion sections set to open).

I am not using JQuery accordion or any other pre-made versions due to some visual aspects in my own design that these did not support.

The JS and CSS I am using toggle 2 classes .accordion-section (the default) and .expand, which activates when a text link with the class .button is clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var accordionPanels = $('.accordion-section');

$( ".button" ).on("click", function() {

    $(this).next(".accordion-section").toggleClass("expand");

    });
});
```

The .expand class looks like this. I am expanding the height of a div rather than actually displaying a hidden section as I have a background image that needs to be visible when the sections are closed, but stay visible and line up when open.

```
div.accordion-section.expand {
height: auto
}
```

I basically want to apply this class to all sections when the screen is over a specific size and make sure clicking .button links will not revert the sections back to .accordion-content.

I am hoping this is simpler than I am making it for myself. I could probably do it with media queries, but I'm thinking the JS would still interfere and it just seems clunky and unnecessary.

NOTE: I do not have the horizontal menu yet but that is no issue, I just need to get the page showing properly for now.

Comment: I should note I am using a mobile first approach, so the working accordion is present in the initial HTML and CSS and it needs to be changed from this, not to this

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't it be as easy as doing this?

```
.accordion-section {
  height: auto;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 640px){
  .accordion-section {
    height: 0;
  }
  .accordion-section.expand {
    height: auto;
  }
}
```

This way your `expand` class is only effective on small screens. Even if it gets added/removed on large screens, it won't do anything.

Comment: That works for the desktop version and the JS isn't interfering as you've suggested would happen so that's awesome, it isn't working for mobile though because the sections need to be 'closed' so height: 0em; on smaller screens and they're stuck open there too. I might be able to work with this though, I've been fussing over JQuery and all sorts trying to figure something out and I probably don't need that if I can tweak this just right, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't mark the answer above as the right answer as it does not work however; @christian314159 thank you very much for putting me on the right track, I was seriously overthinking the whole issue.

I just needed this little part:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 640px){

    div.accordion-section {
      height: auto;
    }
}
```